# How do I do an email form on xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, email, ios-simulator

How do I do an email form on xcode?

ie:
With a text field, 
a sender's email address field, 
and a sender's name field.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mailViewController setSubject:@"SUBJECT_HERE"];
[mailViewController setMessageBody:@"MESSAGE_HERE" isHTML:NO];

[self presentModalViewController:mViewController animated:YES];
[mViewController release];
```

Comment: Yo dawg. I heard you like mails, so we put a MFMailComposeViewController in yo MFMailComposeViewController. So you can mail while you mail.

Answer (score 4):

If you'd like to send an e-mail from within your iOS application, you will want to use the `MFMailComposeViewController` class.  You can find the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) and some useful [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MailComposer/Introduction/Intro.html) at Apple's iOS Reference Library.